# How do I reduce the lime flavor in my Slow Cooker roast?

Tags: flavor, seasoning, roast

I placed limes in with my roast and now it tastes like Limes. How do I get rid of this over the top Lime Flavor. Any suggestions?

Comment: I could start by making a joke about when life gives you limes then... but I think your only option would be to combine the meat with some other elements. So, you could do something like add a little bit of shredded cabbage, and some bread rolls and shred the mead into sandwiches maybe?

Comment: I know this isn't very helpful, but remember this rule, it's always cheaper to add more ingredients than it is to take them back out.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot get rid of the lime flavor, it's there to stay. Your best course of action is to try and balance the strong lime flavor with sweet and savory flavors, for instance shredding the roast onto a bed of chicory/endive leaves with a soy-honey dressing.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily spice the roast well and go for a lemon and herb flavour. The lightness of the citrus could work well with the heavy flavour of the spices.